# Free Shipping not working

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, shipping, free-shipping, recurring

I have set up the following shipping costs:

- flat rate = 5$ per order;
- free shipping from 40$.

These settings work fine for normal products. But when it comes to recurring profiles (i.e. nominal items), only the 5$ flat rate shows up, even when orders are above 40$. And yet, according to Magento user guide:

> The list of available shipping methods during the shopping cart checkout is restricted to the fixed only (Fixed, Table Rates, and Free).

So the free shipping option should be available for recurring products.

I have tried switching store views, disabling flat rate option, etc. but it was of no help.

Does someone have an idea about what might cause this issue? Maybe it has to do with nominal items not being considered by Magento as part of the order total?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you using any non-default shipping modules for the flat rates? Could your theme maybe hiding/collapsing the recurring profile shipping costs?